# Is it possible to add lists inside a list?

Tags: python, list

I created 2 lists in python `

```
ls = []
a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
i = 0

while i < 5:
    x = a[-1]
    a.pop(-1)
    a.insert(0, x)

    ls.insert(0, a)
    i += 1

print(ls)
```

What I want to do is to add something from the list filled with letters into an empty list and making the result look like this

```
ls = [
['a','b','c','d','e','f'],
['f','a','b','c','d','e'],
['e','f','a','b','c','d'],
['d','e','f','a','b','c'],
['c','d','e','f','a','b'],
['b','c','d','e','f','a']
]
```

I would like to know where I made a mistake in python and the solution.

Comment: `pop` returns the value it is removing; you can simply write `x = a.pop(-1)`.

Comment: thank you for your comment but more detailed code that solves the problem will help me

Answer (score 2):

The list is a mutable object in python, so when you insert the list `a` in the `ls`, you are just adding a reference to the list `a`, instead of adding the whole value.

A workaround would be to insert a copy of `a` in the `ls`. One way to create a new copy of the list is using the `list()` on the list or you can use [copy function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) from copy module. So doing `ls.insert(0, a.copy())` would give the same result as below -

```
ls = []
a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
i = 0

while i < 5:
    x = a[-1]
    a.pop(-1)
    a.insert(0, x)

    ls.insert(0, list(a))     # updated this
    i += 1

print(ls)
```

**Output:**

```
[['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'a'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['f', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]
```

---

Another easy way to get your expected output would be to -

```
ls = []
a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
for i in range(6):
    ls.append(a.copy())
    a = [a[-1]] + a[:-1]
print(ls)
```

**Output :**

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['f', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'a', 'b'], ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'a']]
```